# Equation of plane containing the line and lying at a distance from the point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need to find the equation(s) of the plane containing the line

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=1+k \\
y=1 \\
z = -2k
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

lying at distance 1 from the point (-1,0,1).

I was trying to use "Distance from point to a plane" formula and compose a system, given that I know collinear points on the plane (from the line), however, I apparently miss something to finalize the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a one-parameter family of planes that all include the given line. You can use the distance formula with this to generate a one-variable quadratic equation.

There are several ways to produce this family of planes. For instance, note that their normals must be perpendicular to the line. We can read a direction vector for the line directly from its parameterization: $(1,0,-2)$. By inspection, two linearly independent vectors perpendicular to this are $(0,1,0)$ and $(2,0,1)$, and a point on the line can also be read directly from its parameterization, so, using the point-normal form of plane equation, the equations of two distinct planes that include the line are $y=1$ and $2x+z=2$. Every plane that includes the line has an equation that’s an affine combination of these two equations, yielding $$(1-\lambda)(y-1)+\lambda(2x+z-2) = 2\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y+\lambda z-(\lambda+1)=0.$$ Now use the distance formula with this generic plane equation and solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you elaborate on the last equation, especially, how you are obtaining lambdas or just provide some link to how affine combination of two equations works.

Comment: @KamranPoladov Actually, any nontrivial linear combination $\lambda f(x,y,z)+\mu g(x,y,z)=0$ of the two equations gives another equation of a plane that contains the line. Not all of these linear combinations produce unique planes, though: if $c\ne0$, $c\lambda$ and $c\mu$ generate the same plane as do $\lambda$ and $\mu$. We can thus restrict our attention to combinations with $\lambda+\mu=1$ without missing anything and then eliminate one of these variables.

Comment: @KamranPoladov Another way to look at is is that all of the possible normals lie in the span of $(0,1,0)$ and $(2,0,1)$, so every nonzero linear combination $\lambda(0,1,0)+\mu(2,0,1)$ of them is the normal of a plane that contains the line. But we only care about the normal’s direction—changing the length of the normal doesn’t change the plane that it defines—so we can restrict this to $\lambda+\mu=1$ and then eliminate $\mu$. You get the same equation whether you start with this generic combined normal and form the resulting plane equation or just combine the two equations directly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ the searched plane.Then it must be
$$a+b+d+ak-2kc=0$$ and
$$\left|\frac{-a+c+d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right|=1$$
With our condition we get
$$|3c+d|=\sqrt{5c^2+b^2}$$
or by squaring
$$4c^2+d^2+6cd=b^2$$
with $$a+b+d=0$$ we can substitute $b$
$$b=-a-d$$
and we get
$$4c^2+d^2+6cd=a^2+d^2+2ad$$
or
$$cd=0$$

Comment: You have 4 undefined variables within the two-line system...

Comment: No, since the plane containes the line it must be $$a-2c=0$$